# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (10:48:20:103 | error, network) at index.php

Tags: php, netbeans

I am facing this problem when I try to run a php project on my laptop.
Error is:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (10:48:20:103 | error, network) at index.php

I tried some solutions but none seemed to work.I use Windows 7 64bit, Netbeans 8.1, Google Chrome with adblock+ and netbeans extensions.

Comment: do you have connection to your server? is the server software running? does the firewall allow connections? have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: none of my questions have been explicitely answered by this.

Comment: It is a localhost server and i tried to turn on/off firewall.Nothing seemed to work....it works if i run a html project....

Comment: What kind of server you use? WAMP (or similar)? PHP embedded server? IIS?

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes when a resource fails to load you need to confirm if the resource is actually exists on the server. If it is there on the server but it can't load then it could a file permission problem.

Probably you do not have read access to the file.

It happened to me sometime back that I downloaded a jQuery library version that I didn't have read access to and the resource could not load.

In that case try to change file permissions in the terminal using 

`chmod -R 777`

to the entire directory containing the file and see if it now loads.
Use firebug in the browser to inspect the behavior of the file.